# Draw a gradient filled polygon to use in a selector

Tags: android

I am trying to create a drawable such as this in Android:

[image: Arrow Image]

I don't think a nine patch will work because there is nowhere that can safety scale vertically. So next I tried a shape drawable but it does not support triangles.

I want to render this image on the fly so there are no artifacts. Also I want to be able to use it in a selector, so I need to be able to represent this image in xml. Maybe I need to extend some class to manually make the shape. If so how do I embed a tag in the xml to tell it where to render? Does anyone know where to start with this or have an example of something similar?

I have read the first 10 pages of hits on stack overflow and google and am not getting anywhere. Thanks very much for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a 9-patch would work. For the vertical stretching on the left boundary, fill in the line from top to bottom.

Comment: That actually looks half decent. I suppose its not really using a 9-patch in the conventional sense but if I make a xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi, and ldpi versions of the 9-patch then worst case it only need to stretch around 10% on that vertical stretch. Thanks